# How to upload file in document library in sandbox solution?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sandbox-solution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload file using sandbox solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53212/upload-file-using-sandbox-solution)

How to upload file in document library in sandbox solution ? File upload control is not working sandbox in sandbox solution